# How to split a string and include the delimiters in vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, string

I have string like below:

> string: `"//cXML/Request/OrderRequest/ItemOut[]/ItemDetail/Extrinsic[]/home/idea[]"`

if I seperate the string with "[]" then the output should be like this

output:

```
//cXML/Request/OrderRequest/ItemOut[]

/ItemDetail/Extrinsic[]

/home/idea[]
```

Some times my string like this below also:

> string: "//cXML/Request/OrderRequest/ItemOut[]/@quantity"

Then out put should be like below

Output:

```
//cXML/Request/OrderRequest/ItemOut[]

/@quantity
```

Comment: VB.Net has the String.Split method - but it will not include the delimiters (`[]`).  If you had to have the delimiter included, you can always append it to each string result from the split.

Comment: yes but if my string like this "//cXML/Request/OrderRequest/ItemOut[]/@quantity" Then the out put should be like "//cXML/Request/OrderRequest/ItemOut[]"  "/@quantity". Then please tell me how to write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
Regex.Split(str, "(?<=\[])(?=.)");
```

This will include the `[]` in the split results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Dim s As String = "//cXML/Request/OrderRequest/ItemOut[]/ItemDetail/Extrinsic[]/home/idea[]"
Dim results() As String = Regex.Split(s, "\\[]")
For Each s1 As String In results
    Console.WriteLine(s1)
Next
```

To include the delimiter, append it in the split result

Comment: i am getting an exception like "parsing "\\[]" - Unterminated [] set."

Comment: It's because there's an extraneous backslash.